# What is the fastest way to level up adventure rank in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

After hitting Adventure Rank 25 yesterday it feels like all the progress I've had grinding ranks has slowed to a halt. I do my daily commissions and try to get chests whenever I see them. Outside of the story quests, I have no world quests left to do.  I feel like I've hit a standstill and have no idea how to get back up to speed like I was doing prior to Adventure Rank 25.

What is the fastest way to level up adventure rank in Genshin Impact?

Comment: Seems that farming common chests which reset daily is popular. There are farming routes on Reddit and the interactive map https://genshin-impact-map.appsample.com/#/

Comment: You really have it down. Dailies and chests are all you can do. Ever since ~28 or so it's been a slog, and I think that's intentional. You can however do quests - explore town areas and grab any sidequests you might have missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Do daily commissions.  Completing daily commissions and the bonus yields 1300 exp per day.
2. Use Resin whenever possible. Resin converts at a ratio of 5 exp:1 Resin, so it doesn't matter what activity you do so long as you spend it.
3. Complete as many single-time Domains as you can. Certain domains found around Tevyat can only be cleared once, but grants exp for doing so.
4. Complete the Experience Book objectives as much as possible. Each entry grants 100 exp and can go a long way towards ranking up.

[image]

5. Complete as many side quests and story quests as you can.  Story quests are often the greatest source of exp as they can grant anywhere from 300-2000 exp depending on the chain.
6. Explore the world -- you are bound to find many chests and puzzles yielding chests just by exploring Mondstadt and Liyue.  Chests can grant anywhere from 10-30 exp based on their rarity.
7. Collect those Geoculi and Anemoculi!  Ranking up the Statues of the Seven to rank 10 can yield lots of exp, in addition to boosting your max stamina.